# How would Red Kryptonite affect an evil Kryptonian

Tags: dc, superman, smallville

Red Kryptonite brings out the rebellious and immoral personality of Kryptonians and rids them of their inhibitions. However, how would the Red rock affect a Kryptonian like Zod, who was already sadistic, cruel and ruthless.

Martha stated 'it doesn't change who you are, it just dampens your inhibitions. You need to start being  more honest about the way you fee'. Going by this, It amplifies what is already there(Your feelings).

Alternatively, how would it effect a krptonian who never suppressed their true thoughts and emotions for example, a person who was completely happy in life, someone that wasn't holding anything back. Would they just become more lazy?

Answer (score 3):

A good person can do bad things when they are drunk... A bad person might do even worse.  I liken the red kryptonite to alcohol or drugs.  Therefore, I don't think it would be very different regardless of the kryptonian and his personality.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I say that the red kryptonite  would make you a worse person than you are, and it would eventually ware off just like drugs or alcohol, but it would take a ***lot*** longer.